# Data Populate Through JS Ajax call Issue

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, web

I am populate data on HTML Page through JavaScript from database using AJAX Call it populates correctly sometime while sometimes not

HTML Portion

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="properties">
        <div data-role="content" class="hs-content">
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="basic-info content-wrap">
                    <div class="skip-line"><h3>Select your weapon</h3></div>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="weaponList"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
getWeaponsList : function()
{
    var sUrl = "weapons.php";
    WS.request( sUrl,null,'POST', successHandlerUC, failureHandlerUC, false );
    function successHandlerUC( o )
    {
        $('#weaponList').empty();
        var li = '';
        var response = WS.getResponseXML( o );

        // Getting Weapons From DataBase
        var weapons = response.getElementsByTagName('weapon');
        //alert("Total Weapon : "+weapons.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < weapons.length; i++)
        {
            var weapon = weapons.item(i);

            var id = weapon.getElementsByTagName('id');
            id = $(id.item(0)).text();

            var name = weapon.getElementsByTagName('name');
            name = $(name.item(0)).text();

            li += '<li id="'+id+'";><a href="animal-data.html" onClick="HarvestData.saveWeapon('+id+',\''+name+'\')"><span><img title="swords" src="images/bow.png"></span>'+name+'</a></li>';

        }

        $('#weaponList').append(li);
        $('ul#weaponList').listview('refresh');
    }

    function failureHandlerUC( o )
    {

    }
}
```

Sometimes it show all data on html page but sometime it is not showing any data on page however the in both cases data is come from response (Checked By Using FireBug and Web Developer PlugIn In Firefox)

What is the error or any other problem??
Thanks In Advance

Comment: So you always get a response with the data that you're expecting, but sometimes that data doesn't get written to the page?

Comment: Because the function works sometimes then I would be looking at the sURL value and checking it's return results.

Comment: @matthewpavkov yes same situation

Comment: @jeff yes sURL is my php file path where it return xml response the response comes all time but sometime it displayed on html page and sometime not i don't understand why this happens i tried much but not get anything yet that why this happen?

Comment: `listview` is for jQuery mobile, I believe. Is that what you're using? Have you verified that the `li` variable always contains HTML that can be added to the document? Use `console.log(li)` to make sure it has the data that you're expecting. Post the contents of `li` so we can see the actual HTML that you're trying to add to this `<ul>`.

Comment: Does the sURL or post data change? Maybe the returned data (xml) has an error and isn't being loaded. Complete your failureHandlerUC() function  as this might help with debugging.

Comment: @jeff i put alerts in failureHandlerUC() function so that i am sure about that failureHandlerUC() function not executes so i am doing what "matthewpavkov" said then i will check that what the problem is and share here

Comment: @matthewpavkov ok i do what you said

Comment: @matthewpavkov i did what you said about console.log(li). SO in console the values are correctly displayed and li have correct value in both case that in which HTML page display correctly or in which HTML page remains blank

Comment: @jeff in both case either the html page display correctly or html page remains blank in both cases the successHandlerUC() function executes normally. so any other suggestion?

Comment: Start the browser debugger (they all have them these days and usually th f12 key will open the beast). Set some breakpoints and watch expressions and single step through you code.

Comment: @jeff i thing can you see the alert that i comment in code when i uncomment this line it will always shows the result in page but also with alert so is this any helpful point?

Comment: Are you sure the HTML is not getting appended? And are you sure the HTML is well-formed? If `li` has what you expect, then the problem must be with the HTML and/or either of the lines `$('#weaponList').append(li);` or `$('ul#weaponList').listview('refresh');`

Comment: @matthewpavkov  i am sure that it is all well formed because sometime it display correctly and if i uncomment the alert line it will always shows the result in page but also with alert so is this any helpful point?

Comment: Sort of. To me that would indicate that some code is trying to run too soon, perhaps. Can you try commenting out the `$('#weaponList').append(li);` and `$('ul#weaponList').listview('refresh');` and just do a `console.log(li)`. Run it many times while monitoring the console in Firebug or the like. You should see your HTML every single time.

Comment: yes and every time the list displayed in console @matthewpavkov

Comment: Ok, that's strange. Keep both of those lines commented out. Create a new, temporary `<ul>` that you can do a `$('#newUL').append(li)` on. Perhaps the problem is with the `listview('refresh')`.

Comment: i checked but nothing happens new same case like pervious
@matthewpavkov

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Nothing is ever appended to this new `ul`? Can you post what you're seeing in the `console.log(li)`?

Comment: @matthewpavkov this is what which displayed on console  "<li id="1"><a href="animal-data.html" onClick="HarvestData.saveWeapon(1,'Rifle')"><span><img title="swords" src="images/bow.png"></span>Rifle</a></li><li id="2"><a href="animal-data.html" onClick="HarvestData.saveWeapon(2,'Shotgun')"><span><img title="swords" src="images/bow.png"></span>Shotgun</a></li>"
there are 8 li i put only 2 becasuse of space

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what else to try. Take the output from `li` and try to `append()` it directly to an element (any element) and see if that works. There must be something else going on, but I'm not sure what it would be. Maybe you should set up a http://jsfiddle.net to see if you can replicate the issue there and then share that with us here.

Comment: @matthewpavkov
This is a link where i put demo http://engineers-web.com/F09/test
User name is demo@demo.com password is "142536" the first page that you see after login click on continue button the next page will be the list og animals like i put in question list of weapons

Comment: Ok, I took a look. How do I get `getWeaponsList` to execute?

Comment: @matthewpavkov
first u should select any animal then its type then u are at weapon list
but first tow also same things with same problems you can see the first list its same just li values different

Comment: I don't see any animals. All I see is the title "Select animal type". Also, did you know that you're getting an error on that page for `$("#gallerypopup a").photoSwipe(options);` where `photoSwipe()` is not recognized as a function?

Comment: I reloaded everything, logged in again, and that error is gone and I see a list of animals now. I'm also seeing the console output for the `li`.

Comment: You need to fix the error with `$("#gallerypopup a").photoSwipe(options);` which could be causing the problem. Either fix it or remove it. You can't debug with that error happening.

Comment: ok i will first fix this error after that i share my results that solve my problem or not @matthewpavkov

Comment: @matthewpavkov i solve my problem through the points that you notify if you put it in Answer so i will mark as accepted answer thanks :)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure which part helped you. I posted an answer, please let me know if what I posted is not what helped you and I'll edit my answer to reflect the bits that actually helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the main problem you were facing was due to additional JavaScript code (not posted in the question) that was causing an error, which was causing the issues discussed in the question. The code you posted should work as is (as far as the HTML getting appended).

I believe this line was the culprit:

```
$("#gallerypopup a").photoSwipe(options);
```

This was getting called and no such function `photoSwipe()` existed. This was most likely causing the strange behavior the OP was seeing.

The bottom line here is, you need to debug your code. If there is an error "unrelated" to the problem you're seeing, fix that error first. Then see if you still have the problem.

Comment: @mathewpavkov sorry for this but can you do that go to following link http://engineers-web.com/F09/test/ username is demo@demo.com and password is 142536 after login click on Harvest at the bottom of page then chose skip and also on next page click on skip then put some date and continue then at that page there should be the list of Animal but the same problem arise it shows only sometime please help me out from this problem i will be very thankful of you

Comment: @user2651088 I can't log in.

Comment: check now
demo@demo.com  142536